# How is a composite fuselage repaired when structurally damaged?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, aerospace-materials

In case of FOD, a fuselage puncture for example, what is the repair process? Considering time, complexity and cost, how is compared if it was an aluminium fuselage?

Comment: This is very broad @Anton, are you thinking about a specific type of damage?

Comment: Speaking for myself and not in aviation, I find fiber-reinforced plastic much easier to repair than anything made of metal. It's basically doing fiberglass layup, but with a different fiber and maybe different resin.

Comment: @Harper, I agree with you when it comes to FRP repairs done to simple everyday objects. I have done some repairs to Fiber-reinforced-polyester surfboard, and found it quite simple as well, but in aviation may be a whole different story. And I´m also interested in the comparison with aluminium repairs.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty broad and covers a wide range of techniques.  But the airplane Structural Repair Manual (SRM) provides guidance, depending on the extent of the damage.  Typically it involves excising the damaged or delaminated structure and patching the affected area.  As with metal airframes, if the damage it too extensive the airframe may have to be written off as a total loss.